# When I open blender it loads a previous project

Tags: 3d-view

when I open up blender it loads a previous project. When I load factory settings it resets but then when I re-enter blender, the project is still there!!! I don't know what to do I tried deleting it but it just won't[image: what i see when i open blender] work.

Comment: Most likely you saved a project as the default project. Reset to factory defaults, and then press Ctrl+U to save the default project.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you have inadvertently saved that file as your startup file.   I'd make sure you have a backup of that old project file.    Delete all the objects that you see.   Then select (File, Save Startup file).   Close and re-open Blender and see if that's more to your liking.